# Make image or div slide up or down when hovering parent div

Tags: html, css, hover

I currently have this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HwQcf/).

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="refTable">
    <div class="refRow">
        <div class="refCell"><img src="images/test.jpg" /><p>Test 1</p></div>
        <div class="refSep"></div>
        <div class="refCell"><img src="images/test.jpg" /><p>Test 2</p></div>
        <div class="refSep"></div>
        <div class="refCell"><img src="images/test.jpg" /><p>Test 3</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.refTable {
    display:table;
    max-width:919px;
    width:100%;
    margin:0px auto;
}
.refRow {
    display:table-row;
}
.refCell {
    display:table-cell;
    width:291px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:16px;
    border:1px #ffffff solid;
    padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;
    background:#eaeaea;
    color:#333333;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    resize: none;
    outline:0;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
.refCell img {
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
.refCell p {
    line-height: 20px;
}    
.refCell:hover {
    border-color:#b32f01;
    background:#ffffff;
    -webkit-transition: color background 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color background 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color background -0.8s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color background 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: color background 0.2s ease-in-out;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#cacaca;
}
.refCell:hover img {
    opacity:0.4;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity -0.8s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.refSep {
    display:table-cell;
    width:20px;
}
```

In the fiddle, no images display in the boxes. However, there normally would be. On hover, the boxes change background color, font color, and, provided there is an image, image opacity. That's fine.

Now, I would like to make it so that, on hover, an image or div "slides" up from the bottom/side/top that says `"Visit this website"`, possibly with some sort of icon.

What is the best approach? I've really been thinking about it, but I can't come up with a solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did this with just `css` `:hover` and `css3` transitions.

This is the css I wrote,

```
.info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.6s ease-in-out;
  left: 0;
  color: #f7f7f7;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.refCell:hover .info {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

I also added this to the `.refCell` class,

```
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
```

The html I added,

```
<span class="info">Click to view website</span>
```

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HwQcf/14/) to see how it works.

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Thank you very much !